# Forward Firebase Analytics Events with Firebase Cloud Functions to 3rd Parties

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

**Context:** We have natively integrated Firebase Analytics Events in our app, I need to now forward these events to 3rd Party marketing & attribution platforms.

As of today, I can either implement:

- Google Tag Manager (GTM), or
- Pass events by using Firebase Cloud Functions (Server-side).

**Question:** The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/extend-with-functions) states one can extend *Google Analytics for Firebase* with Cloud Functions, but with an added clause:

> Only events marked as conversion events are currently supported by
>   Cloud Functions. You can specify which events are conversion events in
>   the Events tab of the Firebase console Analytics pane.

I however stumbled unto this [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/beyond-mobile-tracking-with-firebase-cloud-functions-fb8ed2fe00b3), where the company forwards all their Events with Firebase Cloud Functions (without limitations). I would like some clarification on whether this latter approach is really a best practice, or am I really only constrained to forward 10 Conversion Events through Cloud Functions (as stated in the documentation) ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm also trying to do this using GTM. I encountered a big issue. You have to manually create and pick a lot of event variables, and they are not properly documented at all. I cannot figure out how to get any user property Firebase set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics for Firebase only sends conversion events to Cloud Functions for Firebase.